# List tile with vertical line and image

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a listview with an image and vertical line at the start of the list tile. I will try to explain with an image.

I have tried using a stack with a container for the vertical line, and then an image right after, but it didn't work. I also tried adding a Position.fill to the vertical line, which also didn't work.

```dart
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Image(image: new AssetImage("assets/img/airplane.png")),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 1.0,
                      width: 3.0,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
```

This is what i am trying to achieve.

[image: Example image]

An example of an app on the store that does what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Example image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:
[image]

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  //State must have "build" => return Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Stack(alignment: const Alignment(0.0, 0.0), children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            //Do you need to make Image as "Circle"
            child: Image.asset('images/sanBernardo1.jpg',
                width: 150.0, height: 150.0, fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 50.0,
            child: Container(
                width: 12.0,
                height: 100.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red[400])),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This led me into the right direction, but the vertical lines height is determined by the size of the image. I am trying to get it to run from the top of the list tile, right to the bottom. The image should be a small part of it. If the list tile is expanded the line should also be expanded. I'll update my question with an example of an app that does what I am attempting.

Answer (score 0):

The correct widget for this case is **Stepper**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html
So, you can create progress through a sequence of steps with a lot of built-in functionality.
Also, it could be useful take a look to Material style guide https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html#

[image]